# Trouble with Tables in Outlook 2010 email template

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, email-templates

I'm trying to fix the width to <800px wide, however Outlook messes up the template and the table width becomes > 1000px and the columns are all uneven widths.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. go to the template: http://skif.pk/email/sm1/
2. press CTRL+A to select all
3. go to outlook 2010 to compose a new email, or another rich-text email editor
4. press CTRL+V in the rich-text editor

I have only used inline styles and set widths on everything so I'm not sure where the problem comes from

[image: Outlook 2010 email view]

## Resolved

**Solution:**

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="1" width="120">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="1" width="120">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="1" width="120">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="1" width="120">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="1" width="120">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="1" width="120">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

The first row had no column widths defined previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You setting width wrong. Should be `<table width="780"` not `<table width="780px"`

Comment: same problem if I remove the "px"

Comment: Paste to email message in outlook and you'll see difference :)

Comment: I removed the "px" then pasted to outlook and got the same thing? Or did you mean to take out the inline styles and put the widths all in the tables and tds too?

Comment: Inline styles should work too, but not necessary as emails are still very limited in styling. I would add widths against table elements. To see a difference expand your outlook window to full screen.

Comment: Actually i've resolved the issue... it was the first row that had no column widths defined... now that I have defined them it displays properly. Thanks anyway